# Populating an HTML dropdown box with an R vector

Tags: forms, r, r-rook-package

I am playing around with `Rook` and `googleVis` in an attempt to
produce some interactive charts

I currently have an HTML text box where users can input a date to trigger changes

```
res <- Rook::Response$new()
res$write('<input type="text" name="theDate">')
```

I want to replace this with a combobox

```
res$write('<input type="dropdown" name="theDate">')
```

populated by an R vector similar to this

```
displayDates <- c("12 Mar 1980" ,"19 Mar 1980")
```

It is like a decade since I have done any of this HTML stuff and I'm
also just beginning with `Rook`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(Rook)
dates <- c("12 Mar 1980" ,"19 Mar 1980")

app <- function(env){
    req <- Rook::Request$new(env)
    res <- Rook::Response$new()
    res$write('<select>')
    res$write(paste("<option>", dates , "</option>"))
    res$write('</select>')
    res$finish()
}

s <- Rhttpd$new()
s$launch(name="myapp", app=app)
```

Comment: looks good. I really should have also asked how I reference the selected item for subsequent use as a variable